# How can I prevent Rails from "pluralizing" a column name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, foreigner

I'm using dwilkie's [foreigner](http://github.com/dwilkie/foreigner) plugin for rails. I have a table creation statement that looks like:

```
create_table "agents_games", :force => true, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :agents,     :column => :agent_id, :foreign_key => true, :null => false
  t.references :games,      :column => :game_id, :foreign_key => true, :null => false
end
```

However, this generates the following SQL:

`[4;35;1mSQL (2.7ms)[0m   [0mCREATE TABLE "agents_games" ("agents_id" integer NOT NULL, "games_id" integer NOT NULL) [0m`

I want the columns to be called `agent_id` and `game_id` - not `agents_id` and `games_id`. How can I prevent Rails from pluralizing the columns?

---

I tried the following in my `enviornment.rb` file, which didn't help:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable "agent_id", "game_id"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution to my issue. I had to declare foreign keys separately from references like so:

```
create_table "agents_games", :force => true, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :agent
  t.foreign_key :agents,     :column => :agent_id, :null => false
  t.references :game
  t.foreign_key :games,      :column => :game_id, :null => false
end
```

With this, I could take out the Inflector stuff.

Answer (score 2):

In general, do not fight ActiveRecord's conventions, it's part of what makes AR work so well. However, if for this *one case* you want to make an exception, it's easy enough via some code in your environment.rb, check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Inflector/Inflections.html for an example.

Comment: I added in `ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
   inflect.uncountable "agent_id", "game_id"
end`, but Rails still goes for the plural column.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll get what you want if you use the singular model name in the reference, like this:

```
create_table "agents_games", :force => true, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :agent,     :foreign_key => true, :null => false
  t.references :game,      :foreign_key => true, :null => false
end
```

This is a clearer way, reflecting that each row of your join table will have one agent_id and one game_id, thus will reference one agent with one game.

The additional inflection or foreign key declarations wouldn't be necessary in this case.