# Incorrect pluralizing of column name when creating foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

I'm having a strange problem with Rails 4.2.4. I am creating a new table, which references some others, like this:

```
t.references :local, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
t.references :serie, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
```

when I execute the migration, there is an error when creating the foreign key constraint:

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  no existe la columna «series_id» referida en la llave foránea

which is Spanish for

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column «series_id» referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

meaning there is no "series_id" column in the created table. Of course, it shouldn't be any column with that name.

The correct column name the generation of FK should be looking for is "serie_id", and it does exist.

Now the strangest thing is that it doesn't fail for :local, for instance. It doesn't look for "locales_id", but "local_id" which is correct, and the corresponding FK is created.

I have custom Spanish inflections, and correct pluralizations are:

> local -> locales
>
> serie -> series

however I don't understand why the FK generation seems to be pluralizing in one case and not in the other.

I have found a working solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430026/2553863), which is declaring specifically the foreign keys, like:

```
add_foreign_key :turnos_registrados, :series, column: :serie_id
```

but what I'd like to know is why is this happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Rails does this procedure to get the foreign key column name:

referenced model in migration → (convert symbol to string) → **pluralize** → **singularize**

The pluralization is done when finding a table name for the given referenced model, see [this line in the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L328%5C). Then, the singularization is done when deriving the actual foreign key column **from the previously pluralized table name** (see the [source here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L808)).

However, in English, "series" is a [collective noun](http://speakspeak.com/resources/vocabulary-general-english/common-collective-nouns), so the singular and plural forms are the same. Rails handles this correctly by default:

```
"series".pluralize
# => "series"

"series".singularize
# => "series"
```

But also note this:

```
"serie".pluralize
# => "series"
```

So, the "s" appendix is first added to the `serie` referenced model name and then the singularization yields the same word - "series". I.e. Rails yield the following for the `:serie` referenced model from your migration:

```
:serie → "serie" (conversion to string) → "series" (pluralize) → "series" (singularize)
```

**So this is why Rails tries to look for `series_id` foreign key column but not for `locales_id`.**

You write that you managed to add the correct key manually using `add_foreign_key`. I suspect that you will encounter more problems with your setup later as Rails will still try to derive the foreign key as `series_id`.

Either you'd have to specify the correct (`serie_id`) foreign_key everywhere in your associations or you should define a **custom pluralization rule** for your case. The rule should be added as an initializer that contains:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'serie', 'series'
end
```

Once you have this, the pluralization will work as expected for your particular case:

```
"series".singularize
# => "serie"
```

And with this custom rule I think that even your original migration should work without problems.

Comment: Thanks, BoraMa. Your answer is very detailed and you're right, even the migrations worked. I went on further and found another solution, I'll add it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [BoraMa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36482437/2553863), I went further and found out the "why":

seems that some high-priority Rails default english inflections were getting in the way.

I have an inflection rule

```
inflect.singular(/((?<![aeiou][rndlj])e|a|i|o|u)s([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1\2')
```

which should catch a

```
"series".singularize
```

since

```
2.2.1 :006 > "series".gsub(/((?<![aeiou][rndlj])e|a|i|o|u)s([A-Z]|_|$)/,'\1\2')
=> "serie"
```

but it wasn't working. Somehow, adding the suggested

```
inflect.irregular 'serie', 'series'
```

made it work, but it should work without too. So, I suspected of some pre-defined rule, which can be confirmed (another BoraMa's contribution) in the console because the response to the sentence

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections.singulars
```

will print among others: [/(s)eries$/i, "\1eries"].

In order to get rid of these defaults, adding

```
  inflect.clear
```

to inflections.rb made it. Now it works with the more general rule I originally had.

Comment: Aah, I see, there is indeed a default singularization rule in Rails for "series" → "series". See for yourself in the console: `ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections.singulars` will print among others: `[/(s)eries$/i, "\\1eries"]`.

Comment: Thanks again, you helped me to better understand how all this work. I will add it to the answer.